# Is there any way to decrypt perl script?

Tags: perl, encryption

I wants to decrypt perl script which I have. So is there any online tool available who can do this? I wants any such tool which can do this.

Thank you...

Comment: I have some perlcode which is encrypted and its for some kind of security purpose so I can not paste it here. So I wants to know if any perl encrypter is available using which I can encrypt perl files.

Comment: If its encrypted, how do you know its Perl code?

Comment: If you can't tell us how it is encrypted we can't help you

Answer (score 3):

You can try with,

```
perl -MO=Deparse script.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell you how to decrypt the code without additional information, but, yes, if you can run it, then you can decrypt it.  If you didn't have the means to decrypt it, then the Perl interpreter wouldn't be able to parse or execute it.